# changing webpage mid-animation/only a section of webpage when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, animation, three.js

so basically, i am working on this website, and making the signup/login page. the design is simple: there will be a 3d model on the right, and the signup/login form on the left

let us say we start with the signup page. when the "already have an account? login" button, the 3d model is meant to rotate, and the signup form is supposed to fade out before the login form fades in. the url is also meant to change from https://website-name/signup to https://website-name/login

i don't know how to accomplish this: changing only SOME content of the webpage when a button is clicked, and a new url is loaded, and WHILE my 3d model animation is working

i know there are several ways to load a page without refreshing (ajax mainly, and... react.js maybe? i have not looked into react too much though,) but that still loads a FULL page

one thing i thought was to have all the animations and stuff happen on one page, and when that is done, load the next page lol, but there has to be a better way to do this

Comment: If you want the animation to continue, while you change other content in your page, you clearly do not want to load a new URL because that would replace the whole page. This seems impossible to do, but actually it isn't. You can use [history.pushState();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) in Javascript to change the URL without loading it. Combine this with AJAX to exchange the forms and you're done. However, if you go for this, you would really need to know what you're doing.